# Using SQL how can I group data by time, counting multiple metrics?

Tags: mysql, database

Given a data set that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------
- id -      mac       - time  - 
- 1  - aa:bb:cc:dd:ee - 9pm   - 
- 2  - aa:bb:cc:dd:ee - 9pm   - 
- 3  - aa:bb:cc:dd:ee - 10pm  - 
- 4  - aa:11:cc:dd:ee - 10pm  - 
- 5  - aa:11:cc:dd:ee - 10pm  - 
- 6  - aa:bb:cc:dd:ee - 11pm  - 
- 7  - aa:11:cc:dd:ee - 11pm  - 
- 8  - aa:11:cc:dd:ee - 11pm  - 
- 9  - 22:11:cc:dd:ee - 12pm  - 
-------------------------------
```

What query would result in an output looking like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- time - total - new(2 or more) - passerby(1) - returning(existed previously) -
-  9pm -   1   -   1            -     0       -           0                   -
- 10pm -   2   -   1            -     0       -           1                   -
- 11pm -   2   -   0            -     0       -           2                   -
- 12pm -   1   -   0            -     1       -           0                   -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why is the total for `9pm` only `1`, not `2`?

Comment: Do you not want to count duplicate `mac` values? Use `COUNT(DISTINCT mac)`

Comment: Correct on not wanting to count duplicate mac values. Yet there are also other metrics to calculate.
Thank you `COUNT(DISTINCT mac)` helps and gets me closer to solving the problem.

Comment: There are other questions on SO about comparing rows to previous rows.

Comment: Ya know, I'm sure there are, I just wanted help with my specific case. I've been trying to solve this for many hours now. Thanks for your incite though!